# How to associate two model classes that point to a common table using CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to implement a comment and reply (on comments) system using cakePHP. I am storing both comments and replies in a common table

```
comments<d, post_id, user_id, text, created, type>
```

using the following code. Here `type` is an enum with possible values `comment` and `reply`.

```
//File: Models/Comment.php
class Comment extends AppModel{
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Reply' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'post_id',
            'className' => 'Comment',
            'conditions' => array('Comment.type'=>'reply')
        )
    );
}
```

```
class Reply extends AppModel{
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Comment'=> array()
        )
    );
}
```

I suppose the code is self explanatory. I came only this far, but the association is not  working.

Comment: Could you explain a bit further? You say you have two separate models, Comment and Reply, but both refer to the same table. So, you *need* to have them in separate models? I mean, a reply to a comment isn't really just another comment? Could you explain your reasons to separate those on different models? maybe we have another solution for the problem that doesn't involve using two models, but that depends on your project's logic.

Comment: Look into CakePHP's Tree Behaviour.

Comment: @Nunser :You are right. A reply to a comment isn't really just another comment. But if you think it way- A reply is a comment on another comment, where as a comment is by definition a comment on any post. I think it's okay if I put both comments and replies into the same table given I use a column `type` with enum values `comment`, `reply`. What's your take on this?

PS- I didn't mention the column `type` in the table description(refer to question). I have just updated it.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but the point remains, a reply to a comment is just another comment, only of a different type. I think it would be more logical to handle both in just one model. Look into CakePHP's Tree Behaviour as @timstermatic said, and if it's too much, just do a self reference to the same model, and don't get tangled with two models for the same table. Let's say you have 5 more types of comments, are you going to handle them one model for each? If you are still set on doing two models, you have to fix the Reply one, you haven't set a table ($useTable = 'comments') for example.